# Only show categories if entries exist in that category AND in another separate category

Tags: categories, stash

I need to create a megamenu for a site which links to a bunch of category pages.

So I have megamenus for Product Type A & B which are also categories.

Under Product Type A there are headings for Materials, Brand & Usage.

Product Type B will also have a megamenu with a Brand subheading.

At the moment I have a category group for Brands and I'm just listing out all the categories in that group under the respective headings.

So what I need to do is make sure that under the Brand heading for Product Type A that only Brands that have entries that are also assigned to the Product Type A category show, and so on for Type B etc.

For most of the options in these menus I'm just dealing with categories because there won't be any overlap.

But there will for Brands and so I need to look at the entries and then build the list of category options from there.

Any idea how I go about that?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT COUNT(entry_id) num_cat_entries
    FROM
    (
            SELECT  entry_id
            FROM    exp_category_posts
            WHERE   cat_id IN (31, 73)
            GROUP   BY entry_id
            HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT cat_id ) = 2
    ) s"
}
{if num_cat_entries > 0} show the category link {/if}
{/exp:query}
```

Answer (score 0):

What will really make your day is the [GWcode Categories add-on](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories). If you set the parameter show_empty="no" you're good to go. [Documentation here](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories/documentation).

Let us know if we can be of any more help!

EDIT: native EE also has this built in

Comment: You may want to check out the support forums for GWCode at http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/gwcode-categories/viewforum/1444 or contact the developer Leon van Dijk directly.

Comment: Already using that plugin but it didn't do what I needed which was only show a category if it contained entries that existed in that category AND another category at the same time.

Comment: GWCode Categories is also REALLY REALLY SLOW when you have large numbers of categories; it uses terribly inefficient queries.